# Tomcat: Servlet sendRedirect to JSP says: "HTTP Status 405 - HTTP method GET is not supported by this URL"

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

Below is code for a simple Servlet(Process.java), JSP page(index.jsp) and Model(Model.java).

**index.jsp**:

```
<%@ page import="com.example.*" %>

<html>
<head>
<title> Myapp </title>
</head>

<body>
<form action="process.do" method="POST">
UserName: <input type="text" name="username">
<br>
UserID: <input type="text" name="userid">
<br>
<input type="submit">
<br>

<%
Model m = (Model) request.getAttribute("model");

if( m != null) {
out.println("Username: " + m.getUserName() );
out.println("UserID: " + m.getUserID() );
}
%>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Process.java**:

```
package com.example;

import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

public class Process extends HttpServlet {

    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException {
        Model m = new Model();
        m.setUserName( request.getParameter("username") );
        m.setUserID( Integer.parseInt( request.getParameter("userid") ) );

        request.setAttribute("model", m);
        response.sendRedirect( request.getRequestURI() );
    }
}
```

**Model.java**:

```
package com.example;

public class Model {

    private String userName = "";
    private int userID = -1;

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public void setUserID(int userID) {
        this.userID = userID;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public int getUserID() {
        return userID;
    }
}
```

**web.xml**:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Process</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.example.Process</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Process</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/process.do</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I am using Tomcat7 and I have deployed this app in context /myapp.
I am able to view index.jsp page correctly, but when I submit the form, I am getting below error:

```
HTTP Status 405 - HTTP method GET is not supported by this URL
```

Comment: Edit: My goal here is to redirect to original index.jsp page from the Process servlet. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to accomplish with `response.sendRedirect( request.getRequestURI() );` ?

This will instruct browser to send a GET request to `/process.do` which is not handled in servlet(You are extending only doPost). If you want to go back to index.jsp just have `response.sendRedirect( "index.jsp");`

EDIT:

Because you want model attribute to be accessed in index.jsp, we cant actually do a browser redirect. Instead a server redirect is needed.

`request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp").include(request, response)` instead of `response.sendRedirect()` should work for you.

Comment: My goal here is to redirect to original index.jsp page. How can I achieve that?

Comment: `response.sendRedirect("index.jsp")` incase you dont want the hardcoding, pass this return url as a parameter during form submit itself

Comment: Thanks! It did redirect to index.jsp, but my model is not accessible to index.jsp, I am seeing same empty form after submit.

Comment: In that case take a look into `RequestDispatcher`

Comment: I am updating answer with that.

Comment: I tried using RequestDispatcher, but then my browser is showing URL of process.do. I need it to go to index.jsp.

Comment: You cant have both, if you need your url to point to index.jsp, that means it is a result of direct get request from browser. Another option is to use session. Ie use response.sendRedirect('index.jsp') but also use `request.getSession().setAttribute()` instead of `request.setAttribute`  and `request.getSession().getAttribute()`, this will ensure model is preserved across multiple requests.

Answer (score 0):

You are not redirecting to `JSP`. Let me explain what happens is when you `post` the form url changes to `http://domain.com/../process.do` and when you use `request.getRequestedUri()` it gives to the url of servlet and it doesn't have `doGet()` method hence you are getting that error. You should use `response.sendRedirect("index.jsp")` to redirect to your `index.jsp` file .

Answer (score 0):

When ,you use the "response.sendRedirect()" method ,it will handover the request object to the browser .so,you can't handle request object any more.Use  "RequestDispacther"  instead of
  "sendRedirect".I hope  ,this may  give you a clarity.Don't Mind,if iam not reach you.